# sesstionStorage cache system with Angular 2 is giving WebStorm errors

Tags: angular, typescript, webstorm, angular2-services, session-storage

I have a large data structure that I want to avoid making an API call every time a user hits the page, so I want to store it in sessionStorage. My `this.fethData(market)` method should handle the logic of whether or not the data exists in the sessionStorage.

This is what I have:

```
             this.fetchingPromiseMap.set(market, 
                this.fetchData(market))
                .toPromise().then((results: any) => {
                this.sessionStorageService.setItem(market, results);

               // the rest of the code isn't necessary for this question
```

Here's the method:

```
    private fetchData(market: string): Promise<any> {
    return 
    this.http.get(`${this.getDispositionURL(market)}`).map((response) 
    => response.json();
    }
```

Do I have a syntax problem? My WebStorm has a ridiculous amount of red font ever since I made these changes....

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

you are missing one closing ). ...response.json()**)**;

```
private fetchData(market: string): Promise<any> {
  return this.http.get(`${this.getDispositionURL(market)}`).map((response) => response.json());
}
```